# IDA Pro. How to select ARM or THUMB mode when using "Make Code" command

Tags: ida, disassembly, arm

How to select ARM or THUMB mode when using "Make Code" command?

I have ARM binary and I want to specify ARM or THUMB code making manually in IDA, but how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When IDA first analyzes the binary, it detects which parts of the code are ARM, and which part are THUMB instructions. Then, it creates segments according to the analysis, and marks each segment as a "THUMB" or "ARM" segment.

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> to see which segment has which type (Value 00=ARM, 01=THUMB).

Press <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> to change the designation of the current segment (the one the cursor is in right now).

If you aren't satisfied with what the analyzer created, use the Edit/Segments submenus to move, resize, create, or delete them.

Comment: `strg` is called `ctrl` outside of Germany.

Comment: Sorry.  Fixed it.

Comment: @Iddo It shows the ranges of memory where IDA has determined the T setting (0 or 1) during analysis.